# Why can't TreeSet have student ages similar when the whole student object is unique?

Tags: java, set, treeset

I have a datatype `StudentSet`. It accepts name and age. When I add this to `TreeSet`, students with similar ages are not added. I know that `TreeSet` only add uniques, but i have different name for student so as a whole isn't the `StudentSet` unique? I want to know the reason behind this.

Following is my code

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class StudentSet implements Comparable<StudentSet> {
    String name;
    int age;

    public StudentSet(String name, int age) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student[Name= " + name + "," + " Age= " + age + "]";
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<StudentSet> set = new TreeSet<>();
        set.add(new StudentSet("xyz", 21));
        set.add(new StudentSet("abc", 23));
        set.add(new StudentSet("xyxyxr", 24));
        System.out.println(set.add(new StudentSet("aaaaaa", 20))); //prints false
        System.out.println(set.add(new StudentSet("bbbbbb", 20))); //prints false
        System.out.println(set.add(new StudentSet("cccc", 20))); //prints false

        TreeSet<StudentSet> sort = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<StudentSet>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(StudentSet o1, StudentSet o2) {
                return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
            }
        });

        sort.addAll(set);
        System.out.println("Sorting According to Name\n");
        for (StudentSet s : sort) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        System.out.println();

        sort = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<StudentSet>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(StudentSet o1, StudentSet o2) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Sorting According to Age\n");
        sort.addAll(set);
        for (StudentSet s : sort) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        System.out.println();

        sort = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<StudentSet>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(StudentSet o1, StudentSet o2) {
                int lastIndex1 = o1.name.lastIndexOf(" ");
                int lastIndex2 = o2.name.lastIndexOf(" ");

                String lastName1 = o1.name.substring(lastIndex1);
                String lastName2 = o2.name.substring(lastIndex2);
                if (lastName1.equals(lastName2)) {
                    return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
                } else {
                    return lastName1.compareTo(lastName2);
                }
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Sorting According to Last Name\n");
        sort.addAll(set);
        for (StudentSet s : sort) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(StudentSet o) {
        return ((Integer) this.age).compareTo(o.age);
    }
}
```

#### **Update:**

The main culprit was that i have set the `compareTo()` method in `StudentSet` to compare ages, which the `TreeSet` internally uses to both compare and check for uniqueness.

Here is my corrected and satisfied code.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(StudentSet o)
{
    int i = Integer.compare(this.age, o.age);
    if (i == 0)
        return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
    else
        return i;
}
```

Comment: your `compareTo` method just uses `age` as a parameter for comparison and uniqueness of the object.

Comment: Read the `TreeSet` javadoc. It says that elements are considered equal by using the `compareTo` (or `compare`, if using `Comparator`)

Comment: Thank you all.so i must remove the comparator form the initial StudentSet class?

Comment: @ShubhamKharde does any solution works for you.

Comment: yeah.thanks for clearing that out @ankur-singhal. i didnt know that implementing Comparator is also the test for uniqueness

Comment: @ShubhamKharde please upvote as well, to remove the downvote

Comment: @ShubhamKharde No, you must redefine it to encompass all the attributes you want to sort on. Implementing `Comparable` is mandatory unless you provide a `Comparator`, but in either case `TreeSet` is going to enforce uniqueness accordingly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Redefine your `compareTo` method, `StudentSet` is your own custom object, so by implementing `Comparable` interface, you are telling compiler to add to `TreeSet` following your implementation.

The implementation below say, if `age` of two or more `StudentSet` are same, then they are <strike>unique</strike> equal.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(StudentSet o)
{
    return ((Integer) this.age).compareTo(o.age);
}
```

Modify the implementation as below,

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(StudentSet o)
    {
         int i = ((Integer) this.age).compareTo(o.age);
            if (i == 0)
                return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
            else
               return i;
    }
```

The above will check for both `Age and Name` and if same, the your object is unique.

Comment: @ShubhamKharde corrected, if any other mistake please correct it and mark as answer

Comment: You should use [`Integer.compare(x,y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-) instead so you don't have to cast to `Integer`. `int i = Integer.compare(this.age, o.age);`.

Comment: @maba Good change suggested, edit accepted, please change.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating 4 `TreeSet` instances, each with a different `Comparator`. The `Comparator` passed to the `TreeSet` determines if two elements are considered to be identical.

In the first `TreeSet`, you are not passing any `Comparator` to the constructor, which means the natural ordering (defined by `Comparable`) is used. The `Comparable`'s `compareTo` compares by age only.

In the third `TreeSet`, you are using this `compare` method :

```
    @Override
    public int compare(StudentSet o1, StudentSet o2)
    {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
```

Since `compareTo` compares only by age, two `StudentSet` instances having the same age are considered the same, and only one of them will be added to the `TreeSet`.

If you want your original `set` `TreeSet` as well as the 3 `TreeSet`s assigned to the `sort` variable to contain all the unique elements, all your `compare` and `compareTo` methods must sort by all properties that determine a unique `StudentSet` instance.

They can sort the `TreeSet` using different orderings by comparing the properties in a different order each time. For example, one can compare the names first and then the ages (if the names are equal), while another can compare the ages first and then the names (if the ages are equal).

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine as per the implementation of `compareTo` method. If you want it to be based upon `name` not the `ages` then you need to correct this in the `compareTo` method as follows,

```
@Override
public int compareTo(StudentSet o)
{
    return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
    //return ((Integer) this.age).compareTo(o.age);
}
```

Comment: This would again have the problem of not adding similar name but different ages in the TreeSet.This comparator is used for the uniqueness test in TreeSet class.See mine modification in ankur's answer that i have learnt